# \specials in pdftex

Tags: pdftex

In some old documents I used `\special`. However, in my new documents, I want to run pdfLaTeX, because I have other figures in PDF format. If I run pdfTeX on the
`.tex` file, it rejects the `specials`. 
Is there any way to get pdfTeX to accept specials?

Comment: We will need more detail: `\special` is used for 'back end stuff', which could be anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\special` command is basically telling the backend, i.e., the output device, how to behave. Therefore the content of a `\special` command is device dependent and there is now way to make an output device A understand the syntax of device B unless A is accepting what B wants in the first place as well.

Now `pdftex` and thus `pdflatex` use both a "TeX"-engine as well as an output device that generates printer output (PDF data in this case) and it has certain conventions for `\special` but not others. So if your old document has been written for some specific DVI printer device or for example for a PostScript device then no, you can't make those documents work without replacing the content of the `\special` commands.

For precisely this reason LaTeX2e introduced abstraction layers that hide graphic and color `\special` syntax, by providing higher level packages (`graphics`, `graphicx`, `color`) that offer a standard syntax and internally  translate these commands into the `\special` commands the output device needs to load a picture or to select a color or to rotate an image.

Comment: Is there no lucky cases where `\pdfliteral` can save the day?

Comment: @percusse how? if the \special had any direct function (which is supposedly had) like loading a graphic then either you disable the \special in which case the document will render differently or you manually change all specials to use syntax that pdftex supports.

Comment: True of course. I was just wondering if there are any small subset of backend specials shared by all drivers or not. That's probably an irrelevant question related to the issue at hand though.